# Image wont load in my JSP page from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsp

I created table in database and I have problem with loading picture from that database. Type of data that I used for img is blob, I have good connection with database, all other data is showing on my jsp page but picture wont load. Data type of img is .jpg, dimensions of picture are 250x250 and size about 14.2 kb

```
CREATE TABLE `akcija` (
  `idakcija` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naziv` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `cena` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idakcija`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I load data by following insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `games1`.`akcija` (`naziv`, `cena`,`img`)
 VALUES ('TEST','3500', 'C:\\Users\\mlade\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\New Folder (2)\\WebApplication1\\web\\gallery\\ufc4.jpg');

I also tried by right click on field for img and selecting Load Value from File, and then selecting img that I want. And third option that I tried is right click -> open value in editor -> Load image -> Apply -> and Apply on changes
```

Here is my JSP page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@include  file="connection.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%@include file="header.jsp" %>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img class="img-fluid "  src="https://gifcdn.com/1h64r34cpd6coj0dhl.gif" alt="mailtimers.com">
        </div>

        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Ime igrice</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cena</th>
                    <th scope="col">Slika</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <%                String id = request.getParameter("id");
                Blob img = null;
                Connection connection = null;
                Statement statement = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;
                try {
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    String sql = "select * from akcija";
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    int i = 0;
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
            %>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("naziv")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("Cena")%></td>
                    <td><img src="<%=resultSet.getBlob("img")%>" width="250" height="250"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <%
                        i++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.println("Problem");
                    return;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        resultSet.close();
                        statement.close();
                        connection.close();
                    }
                    catch (SQLException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Data from column **naziv** and **cena** is show on jsp page but **image** wont load. See picture

[Picture not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfnUn.jpg)

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Project Structure2]

Here is screenshots of my project structure. Also screenshots of DB and query that I used to insert data in DB

[image: DB screenshot]

[image: Query for inserting data]

Comment: When I inspect web page I am having this error

GET http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/faces/com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@4df066cd 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you are insert query is inserting string  for image or blob?

Comment: I agree with @Swati that you are inserting a string instead of the picture itself. Check [these tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=insert+a+picture+into+blob+using+jdbc) to learn how to do it. By the way, another  common way is to keep the column datatype as `varchar` and then insert the path of the image on the file system (the way you are doing in your insert statement). Then, retrieve the path string (`getString`, not `getBlob`) in the JSP and and put that with `img` tag.

Comment: Thanks for advise @ArvindKumarAvinash . I inserted path of image in DB and retrive path with getString in JSP. Now my problem is that Chrome wont show image, error: Not allowed to load local resource

Comment: @MladenSavic - Put the image folder inside your project > WebContent > resources > images. The folder names, `resources` and `images` can be anything but these are the names which are conventionally used.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, I think that I already put image folder inside my project. Itson this path C:\Users\mlade\OneDrive\Desktop\New Folder (2)\WebApplication1\web\gallery

Comment: @MladenSavic - Somehow (probably because you added a comma after my name) I did not get a notification of your last comment. You still didn't get what I am asking you to do. Don't worry, I will help you. You have to store the relative path in the database. Currently, you are storing the full path from the filesystem. Post the screenshot of your project structure in IDE (Eclipse or whatever IDE you are using).

Comment: Please see below screenshot of project structure. Thank you! @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: @MladenSavic - Insert `gallery/ufc4.jpg` in the DB instead of the full path from the file system. Also, use `resultSet.getString("img")` instead of `resultSet.getBlob("img")` with the `<img>` tag.

Comment: <img src="data:image/png;base64,<%=base64.encode(resultSet.getBlob("img")).%>"/>

Comment: Awesome, it is working now! Thank you very much! Appreciated for your help! @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: @MladenSavic - You are most welcome.